# does uCLinux supports C++11?

Tags: c++11, uclinux

I am trying to use STM32F4 Discovery board with uCLinux BSP. Is it possible to create an application that uses C++11 function calls?
For example : STL, lambda, etc

Comment: it's defined by what compiler it uses. and STL isn't C++11, it's separate library, that present on many platforms for support of legacy code.. you're thinking about standard library

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a GCC based toolchain for that BSP. Lookup which version of GCC is available there. Compare it with this table. https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html